# Is it possible to write an SQL query that returns the values of something that doesn't exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to write an SQL query that returns the rows of a table in which certain data of a column does not appear in another table.

For example, let's say I have two tables:

**Table 1:**

```
Date             Name              Room
2020/01/23       John              201
2020/01/22       Rebecca           203
2020/01/22       Ronald            204
2020/01/22       Jimmy             205
```

**Table 2 (does NOT have the same amount of columns):**

```
Date             Room
2020/01/22       203
2020/01/23       201
2020/01/22       202
2020/01/22       209
```

I want to find all the rows in Table 2 in which the room number does NOT show in table 1. Which means my SQL would return

```
2020/01/22       202
2020/01/22       209
```

Since room 202 and room 209 does not appear in Table 1.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t2.room = t1.room
                 );
```